# Save dataframes to csv from a pdf

Tags: python, dataframe, python-camelot

I am trying to extract tables from a pdf I use camelot library. Already, I am working on the first page of the pdf. There is 3 tables on this page whose 1 useless.
I did this script :

```
from pathlib import Path
import os 
import shutil
import camelot
import pandas as pd

p = Path.cwd() 
save_path= p.joinpath("Tables_csv") 

tables = camelot.read_pdf("file.pdf", pages = "1",line_scale = 20)

for i in range(len(tables)):
    s = tables[i]
    sheet = s.df
    
    print(sheet.head)

    if sheet.head == ["a", "b", "c"]:
        sheet.to_csv(f"abcTable{i}.csv")
        shutil.move(sheet, save_path)
    elif sheet.head == ["d", "e", "f"]:
        sheet.to_csv(f"defTable{i}.csv")
        shutil.move(sheet, save_path)
```

I want to save in csv ["a", "b", "c"] and ["d", "e", "f"] dataframe and in an other folder. But no files are saved (I tried in the current folder too).
I have an idea why this is not working as I want, when I print(sheet.head) it shows all the dataframe between <>.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
sheet.head != ["a", "b", "c"] or ["d", "e", "f"]
```

is interpreted by python as

```
(sheet.head != ["a", "b", "c"]) or ["d", "e", "f"]
```

due to [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) which always is true as non-empty list is considered to be truthy. Is your aim for this condition to be always `True`?

```
sheet.drop
```

Here you are just accessing drop. If drop is method of sheet is your aim to merely access it rather than calling it?

```
for i in range(len(tables)):
    ...
    for i in sheet:
        sheet.to_csv(f"sheet{i}.csv")
```

You use `i` for both loops, this is legal, but when you refence `i` inside nested `for` loop it pertains solely to inner loop, there is no way to easily access `i` of outside loop. Is that your aim?

Comment: So i should do for  if sheet.head != (["a", "b", "c"]) or ["d", "e", "f"]): ? 
For sheet.drop I want to delete the dataframe if the header is not ["a", "b", "c"] or ["d", "e", "f"]